# Adding array key dynamically PHP

Tags: php, arrays, silex

I'm creating a dynamic form in Silex that alters depending on need.

If  `$disabled = 'true'`

How would I change:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')

->add('email', 'email', array(
    'data' => $from
))
```

to

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')

->add('email', 'email', array(
    'disabled' => true,
    'data' => $from
))
```

Comment: Just a general comment - be careful with `true` as a boolean value and 'true' as a string. You seem to use both, which is a way to fail somewhere. And the answer below also compares potentially boolean value with string, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish it like this:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form');

$options = array(
    'data' => $from
);

if($disabled == 'true'){
    $options['disabled'] = true;
}

$form->add('email', 'email', $options)
```